# something went wrong during video to numpy conversion

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tfrecord

I use video2record to deal with some short video, I want to turn them into tfrecord then I can input them into tensorflow. 
Then I use videorecord on github: https://github.com/ferreirafabio/video2tfrecord
But when I run it, the error said numpy wrong
here are my code(python):

```
from video2tfrecord import convert_videos_to_tfrecord

convert_videos_to_tfrecord(source_path="video", destination_path="video", n_videos_in_record= 1 , n_frames_per_video = 5 , file_suffix="*.mp4")
```

here are the error:

> > AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
> >           1 from video2tfrecord import convert_videos_to_tfrecord
> >           2 
> >     ----> 3 convert_videos_to_tfrecord(source_path="video", destination_path="video", n_videos_in_record= 1 , n_frames_per_video =
> >     5 , file_suffix="*.mp4")
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/video2tfrecord/video2tfrecord.py
>   in convert_videos_to_tfrecord(source_path, destination_path,
>   n_videos_in_record, n_frames_per_video, file_suffix,
>   dense_optical_flow, width, height, color_depth, video_filenames)
>       174       total_batch_number = int(math.ceil(len(filenames) / n_videos_in_record))
>       175     print('Batch ' + str(i + 1) + '/' + str(total_batch_number) + " completed")
>   --> 176     assert data.size != 0, 'something went wrong during video to numpy conversion'
>       177     save_numpy_to_tfrecords(data, destination_path, 'batch_',
>       178                             n_videos_in_record, i + 1, total_batch_number,
>
> AssertionError: something went wrong during video to numpy conversion

Comment: I don't know if you'll find anyone here who knows about tfrecord. I'd submit this question as an issue on their github page

Comment: ok, I'll go to his github to submit an issue